# Use percent '%' as an argument of SASS function

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I need to pass **'%' unit** sign as an argument for my mixin. While passing '**px**'/'**vh**' etcetera has no problem, compiler refuses to work with percent sign.

[image: percent error]

With **px** there is no problem.

[image: px doen't have a problems]

The same problem exists if I want to add percentage sign after function call.

[image: no matter with having '+' or not]

This seems weird because it works perfectly with another units.

Is there a way to use percentage sign without modifying the output of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you can use interpolation.

```
width: nth($params, $i)#{'%'};

and

@include scrollable-table-by-every-column-width(#{'%'}, auto, 15, 10, 20, 20, 15, 15, 5);
```

**UPD**

In a case where you need percents after function call you can use [percentage](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#percentage) function as well. But you need to keep in mind that this function literally does `num * 100`. So in this case with

```
width: nth($params, $i) +%;
```

You can do next:

```
percentage(nth($params, $i) / 100) //assuming you passed already calculated percents (not 0.2, 0.3.., but 20, 30...)
```

But this doesn't resolve problem when you want to pass percentage sign as an argument.